# Possible to use TestNG DataProvider AND test suite Parameters?

Tags: testng, data-driven-tests

Does anyone know if there is a way to use a TestNG **DataProvider** with a test at the same time as using the **@Parameter** annotation?  Our test suites have some constant configuration information that is being passed to the test methods via the @Parameter annotation.  We would now like to use a DataProvider to run these tests over a set of data values.

I understand the internal problem of determining the order the resulting parameters would be in but we need to this feature if possible.

Any thoughts?

In an ideal world, I could do something like this:

```
@Test(dataprovider = "dataLoader")
@Parameters("suiteParam")
public void testMethod(String suiteParam, String fromDataParam) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Hey, it may be a bit clunky but why don't you use a @BeforeClass method to store the suiteParam locally on a field of the test class like so.

```
private String suiteParam;

@BeforeClass
@Parameter("suiteParam")
public void init(String suiteParam) {
  this.suiteParam = suiteParam;
}
```

This way you can use your data providers in the usual way and still have access to your suite param.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using the using [TestNG's dependency injection capabilies](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependency-injection). You can access all defined parameters in your DataProvider. This is some example DataProvider in need of the test_param parameter:

```
@DataProvider(name = "usesParameter")
public Object[][] provideTestParam(ITestContext context) {
    String testParam = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("test_param");
    return new Object[][] {{ testParam }};
}
```

This way you can collect configured and generated parameters in a DataProvider which is then used for your test. See the [TestNG JavaDoc](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestContext.html) for details on the ITestContext class.